# Multimodal classification - multiple images for each record

Tags: classification, transformer, encoding, image, finetuning

I have a multimodal classification task. In my dataset, each record consists of

- a text
- a list of 1 to 4 associated images
- a label

Probably, I'd want to use transformers encoders to represent both text and images and then fine-tune them.

In your experience, what is the best way to represent a variable number of images associated with the same record?

(I also thought of taking the average of the different image embeddings or similar approaches. I might do so if I froze the encoder, but I want to fine-tune it).